# Are there some estimates of average working hours in Medieval England?

Tags: labor-economics, economic-history

I am looking for data or estimates on how many hours per day (or week, month, or even year) people used to work on average in Medieval England. Since, in the past, people mostly produced what they consumed at home (for example, food, fuel, clothing, and so on), I would like to find sources for both formal and informal work. These can be two different sources, as long as they examine a similar time period.

Does anyone know of a good dataset, research, or book that addresses these questions?